# select only name who are started like customer1 , customer2 .... not customer

Tags: sql

i have table test

```
id     nm 
 1   customer 
 2   customer 1
 3   customer 2
 4   customer 3
 5   customer 4
```

I want to select only name like customer 1 customer 2.....

Comment: Did you try LIKE?

Comment: yea. but it is not giving accurate result select * from test where nm LIKE '%1%';

Comment: If you use it correctly it will give the result you need. Read about it: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT nm
FROM test
WHERE nm LIKE 'customer %';
```

Answer (score 0):

Starts with customer but has more chars.

```
SELECT nm
FROM test
WHERE nm LIKE 'customer%' and len(nm) > len('customer');
```

Comment: thank you very much . cannot vote you up sir . i have a low reputation   yet

Comment: @sachinpotter just mark it as an answer if it's what you need.

Comment: if data is like customer23abc , customer aa 123  then ??

Comment: @sachinpotter if you need to include it the above query is ok. Othewise please ask the other question with detailed business rules.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `in` for a list of specific names:

```
select nm
from test
where nm in ('customer 1', 'customer 2');
```

If you want customers whose name has a space, then you can use `like`:

```
where nm like '% %'
```

or to be more specific:

```
where nm like 'customer %'
```

Answer (score 0):

use _ which mean there should be a letter after the given string

`SELECT nm
FROM test
WHERE nm LIKE 'customer _';`